# What could cause a table hierarchy to render incorrectly in IE9?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-9, repeater

I have a bunch of nested ASP.net repeaters, which each generate table structures when I link the outermost repeater to an Object data-structure that I have made.  It renders exactly how I would expect when run in Chrome, Firefox, or IE9 (in compatibility mode).

But when I run it in regular old IE9, seemingly random spaces will appear in the tables, containing no data, and sometimes even running off the outermost border of the table itself.

All I am wondering is if anyone has any possible *ideas* as to what could cause such peculiar behavior or heard of similar issues?

Comment: Can you at least post the generated code...

Comment: What css constructs are you using? Maybe try some css reset and then build up from there.

Comment: My system is missing telepaty.dll, so can you please post generated HTML?

Comment: At a high level, you cannot blame this on the repeater because it doesn't add any html, it just uses exactly what you put in the item templates. I would suggest sharing the html and css (and adding a CSS tag to the question.)

Comment: actually my first thought was to analyze the html by doing a view source but i cant actually see any HTML for the tables.  is this perhaps because i wrapped everything in an updatepanel? i will try to remove it and see if i can get some actual HTML

Comment: so i commented out all the updatepanel stuff and it rendered correctly in plain IE9....so im not really sure how to debug this actually since the updatepanel appears to be hiding the actual HTML being rendered?

Comment: @chilleo, side note: as "regular old IE9" you mean actually IE9 mode, unlike "IE9 compatibility" which is IE7/8? It is also interesting that the list where it does not run correctly includes most browsers - looks like only Opera/Safari rendering your HTML correctly...

Comment: @chilleo Can you show us what css is being applied to the update panel?

Comment: @alexei it renders *correctly* in chrome, firefox, and IE9 (compatibility mode). it is non compatibility mode where it renders *incorrectly*

Comment: @chilleo, right... I guess I read "expect" as "except"... need to get more coffee... To see dynamically inserted HTML in IE use dev tools (F12) and click on elements you need with picker. At the same time check "styles" and "layout" tabs to see if spaces are caused by CSS or content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug in IE9 that is caused by spaces between table cells. Please see this answer for a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230802/84236